# Conditional display faults

Tags: conditional-tags

I'm trying to get the line of codes below to display it's content on "web-design-portfolio" and "web-design-portfolio-2" but it ends up messing up every other pages on my website and displays the "Ul" element on them. Any ideas what the problem could be.

```
<?php 

is_page(array('web-design-portfolio','web-design-portfolio'));  { ?>

<div id="content-box-gallery">



      <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"></a></h2>



            <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>

          <div id="thumber">  <?php the_post_thumbnail($size, $attr); ?></div><?php } ?>



            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php endwhile; else: ?>

            <h2>Woops...</h2>

<p>Sorry, no posts we're found.</p>

            <?php endif; ?>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="http://siteripe.com/web-design-portfolio/">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://siteripe.com/web-design-portfolio/">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://siteripe.com/web-design-portfolio-1/">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://siteripe.com/web-design-portfolio-1/">&raquo;</a></li>
           </ul>

</div><!-- End Content Box  Gallery --> 


  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) returns `boolean true` or `boolean false`.  The way you've called it looks like it would have no effect.

Try this:

```
if ( is_page( array( 'web-design-portfolio', 'web-design-portfolio-2' ) ) ) {
?>

<!-- All your display code code -->

<?php }   // ends the if() statement
```